# Creating cloudwatch Alarm using AWS CLI having Math expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, opensearch

I created a alarm for monitoring AWS Opensearch in GUI. I was able to create it successfully, I need to do the same thing AWS CLI via Bash script so I could reuse the Command for creating more alarms. But I was not able to do that. Here is the JSON output of the alarm that I created. It would be great if some one could help me to write CLI command using below JSON output. I mainly **dont know how to use math expression in AWS CLI**.

```
{
    "MetricAlarms": [
        {
            "AlarmName": "koral-alert-opensearch-total-storage-space-dev",
            "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:4444442111111:alarm:koral-alert-opensearch-total-storage-space-dev",
            "AlarmDescription": "Alert for the total free space in dev opensearch cluster",
            "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2023-04-28T07:51:06.885Z",
            "ActionsEnabled": true,
            "OKActions": [],
            "AlarmActions": [
                "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:4444442111111:koral-sns-cloudwatch-dev"
            ],
            "InsufficientDataActions": [],
            "StateValue": "ALARM",
            "StateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [7.0 (28/04/23 07:45:00)] was less than or equal to the threshold (10.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
            "StateReasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2023-04-28T07:52:04.484+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2023-04-28T07:45:00.000+0000\",\"period\":300,\"recentDatapoints\":[7.0],\"threshold\":10.0,\"evaluatedDatapoints\":[{\"timestamp\":\"2023-04-28T07:45:00.000+0000\",\"value\":7.0}]}",
            "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2023-04-28T07:52:04.487Z",
            "Dimensions": [],
            "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
            "DatapointsToAlarm": 1,
            "Threshold": 10.0,
            "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold",
            "TreatMissingData": "notBreaching",
            "Metrics": [
                {
                    "Id": "e1",
                    "Expression": "FLOOR(m1/1024*60/PERIOD(m1))",
                    "Label": "FreeStorageSpace",
                    "ReturnData": true
                },
                {
                    "Id": "m1",
                    "MetricStat": {
                        "Metric": {
                            "Namespace": "AWS/ES",
                            "MetricName": "FreeStorageSpace",
                            "Dimensions": [
                                {
                                    "Name": "DomainName",
                                    "Value": "koral-es-dynamodb-b-dev"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "ClientId",
                                    "Value": "4444442111111"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "Period": 300,
                        "Stat": "Sum"
                    },
                    "ReturnData": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "CompositeAlarms": []
}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors using this json?